# Solving for all possible values of an equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the following equation the value of $D$ is known. How can i solve this equation for all possible $r$ and $x$ which would yield $D$?

$$
r\sum\limits_{i=0}^{12}x^{i/12}=D
$$

Comment: For every $x$, just let $r=D\left(\sum_ix^{i/12}\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your answer. If i also know for x yes, but what if x is also unknown?

Comment: You say you want all possible $r$ and $x$. Well, every positive number $x$ gives you a solution; and, for each solution value of $x$, my formula gives you the corresponding solution value for $r$.

Comment: Is there still a problem?

Comment: No the problem solved! Thank you

Comment: By the way how would you solve the same problem if r, x and D are known and 12 is unknown, so if i want to find the number of steps

Comment: So, you want to solve $r\sum_{i=0}^nx^{i/n}=D$ for $n$. Write $q$ for $x^{1/n}$. The equation becomes $r{xq-1\over q-1}=D$, which you can solve for $q$. Then you can solve for $n$ by taking logarithms.

Comment: Can you please provide more steps, how does the equation becomes r(xq-1/q-1) if i write q instead of x^(1/n)?

Comment: $x^{i/n}=q^i$, and $\sum q^i$ is a geometric progression with first term 1, common ratio $q$, and $n+1$ terms.